# animation problems with android comparated with ios

Tags: android, ios, animation, media-player

> Well, for starters I think the biggest problem that I have is to assume or hope that android animations, behave like ios.

I have a time indicator that is updated every 100 milliseconds and I want you to displace fluidly moving their position in x, over time.

In **`IOS`** code:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1f target:self selector:@selector(moveIndicator:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

and inside `moveIndicator` function.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.1f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear animations:^{

   _playIndicatorView.frame = CGRectMake(myXpos, _playIndicatorView.frame.origin.y, _playIndicatorView.frame.size.width, _playIndicatorView.frame.size.height);

} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
}];
```

And this looks like:

[image]

**I'm trying to do this in android and animation does not behave as I expect**

Android code:

***For Init the `.1f` timer.***

```
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (!killMoveIndicatorTimer) {
                moveIndicator();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
            }
        }
    };
```

***For call `runnable` i'm using:***

```
handler = new Handler();
runnable.run();
```

***For move the indicator i'm using:***

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(playerIndicatorView, "translationX", myXpos);
anim.setDuration(100);
anim.start();
```

and looks like:

[image]

***and this other option too:***

```
playerIndicatorView.animate().x(myXpos);
```

Looks like:

[image]

I am absolutely sure there must be some way to make this animation as similar as possible to ios.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If I had to guess, your problem is not with the animation, but with other work that you are doing that is tying up the main application thread.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
ObjectAnimator anim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(playerIndicatorView, "translationX", backgroundStripe.getWidth());
anim.setDuration(3000);
anim.start();
```

Main problem with your first example is with `handler.postDelayed(this, 100);` Your animation has duration 100ms and after completion handler will execute next animation after 100ms.

For second example you are not using LinearInterpolator:

```
ViewPropertyAnimator viewPropertyAnimator = playerIndicatorView.animate();
viewPropertyAnimator.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
viewPropertyAnimator.setDuration(2000);
viewPropertyAnimator.translationX(backgroundStripe.getWidth());
```